# Transfer shopping cart from guest to user logged?

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I use https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

I only have authentication by username without password

The problem is the sessions
When I am a guest, the session code is for example

9ot0CjCYUQpYR10ox43A9GoHVp6vliXuFFsoZlGU

After registration it is renewed to a different code

HXTc6LXNEW79QzvrvnKwi2N3IBQWwSroBfghOznR

in config/auth.php

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Modules\User\Entities\User::class,
        ],

        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Modules\User\Entities\Customer::class,
        ],
    ],
```

CACHE_DRIVER=redis

SESSION_DRIVER=redis

in User/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

```
public function verify(VerifyCodeRequest $request)
{
    $customer = $this->customer($request);
    /* code etc. */

    if ($customer->exists) {
     auth()->login($customer,true);
    }
}
```

in Cart/Providers/CartServiceProvider.php

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Cart::class, function ($app) {
            return new Cart(
                $app['session'],
                $app['events'],
                'cart',
                session()->getId(),
                config('fleetcart.modules.cart.config')
            );
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me (original code by @liamjcooper) was creating event listeners.

```
namespace App\Providers;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        /* flash cart items */
        \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting::class => [
            \App\Listeners\PrepareCartTransfer::class
        ],
        /* add flashed cart items to authenticated user cart */
        \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class => [
            \App\Listeners\TransferGuestCartToUser::class
        ]
        /* end cart item */
    ];
```

then ran

```
php artisan event:generate
```

at the listeners

flash the cart content from guest

```
namespace App\Listeners;

    class PrepareCartTransfer
    
    public function handle(Attempting $event)
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            session()->flash('guest_cart', [
                'session' => session()->getId(),
                'data' => \Cart::getContent() 
            ]);
        }
    }
```

transfer cart items to authenticated user

```
namespace App\Listeners;

    class TransferGuestCartToUser
    {
        public function handle(Login $event)
        {
        $userCart = \Cart::getContent();
        $userCartItems = $userCart->toArray();

        if (session('guest_cart.data') != null ) {
            $guestCart = session('guest_cart.data');
            $guestCartItems = $guestCart->toArray();
        }

        if ($userCart->isNotEmpty() && !empty($guestCartItems)) {
            $maxUserCartId = max(array_column($userCartItems, 'id'));

            $guestCartItems = array_map(function ($item) use (&$maxUserCartId) {
                return array_merge($item, ['id' => ++$maxUserCartId]);
            }, $guestCartItems);
        }
```

That did enough to me running stock package.

Comment: Yes, I saw this solution
But it didn't work for me
Perhaps the reason is
I only use email with login without the password
٫٫٫٫٫٫
Because this event is not working for me
Illuminate \ Auth \ Events \ Attempting :: class